# Get Ip used by Nodejs when it makes a request as a client

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, request

I want to get the IP which is used in this request to the URL. I am getting the response required( HTML of the webpage ). Since I want to try to dynamically change Ips using AWS lambda when making a request, I first wanted to see what IP is actually used. Is there a way to get that? I am using 'request-promise' module for this.

NodeJS Code

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    "rejectUnauthorized": false,
    url: URL,
    formData: {
        data:data
    }
}
const response = await request(options)
```

Comment: *"dynamically change Ips using AWS lambda when making a request"* — I don't think that's something you have any control over. Your Lambda instance has the IP it has, usually a non-public internal address, and requests to external networks go through a NAT gateway, whose IP you can't change on a whim either.

Comment: Oh I see. I am trying to figure out a way to send requests using different IPs since if for some reason the URL I am trying to access has a block limit on requests. So AWS lambda will not solve this issue ?

Comment: No. You'll want to use a list of HTTP proxies that you cycle through. There are any number of anonymous proxies to be found out there, but since you have no control over them, they're hardly reliable and will cause a lot of pain. There are probably paid services out there offering reliable proxies with often changing IPs for such a purpose, I'd imagine…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by making an API which makes request to my other NodeJS server. and then printing the IP in the second server.
Also AWS Lambda in default state have changing Ips